# Is there a way to set the inital value of textformfield with data from cloud firestore without the displayed data being enclosed in braces?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retrieving data from firestore and setting the inital value of the textformfield with this data. I am able to get the data, However the data displayed is enclosed in braces and have tried to use regex patterns to work with this but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated

I have tried using regex expression to work around this but nothings working so far.

```
Widget _nextOfKinFirstName() {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore.collection('farmer_profile').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {

    var name = snap.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
      return docs['first_name'];
    }).toString();
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: name,
      validator: (name) {
        Pattern pattern = r'^[a-zA-Z]+$';
        RegExp exp = new RegExp(pattern);
        if (!exp.hasMatch(name))
          return 'enter name';
        else
          return null;
      },
    );
  },
);
```

}

i expect the output to be a string value not enclosed in braces.

This is the output i have
[output on textformfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwujl.png)

while this is the database am testing how to implement with.

[simple database i'm trying this with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVGUF.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: @Synergi as you can see that's what displays on the textfields

Comment: You're transforming the map into a String and that's the value you're getting. Did you tried to actually update the name variable with docs['first_name']?